# SignaturePad on android webview cannot save image to server

Tags: signaturepad

I have made an application (classic asp on local IIS 7.5 server Win 7 Ultimate) and with webview on android i want to take signatures from clients.
Works perfect on PC and tablet with android 5.1.
But when i run the app on mobile with Android 7 or tablet with Android 4.4.2 creates error on line

```
function SaveToBase64 (base64String)
Set Doc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
Set nodeB64 = Doc.CreateElement("b64")
nodeB64.DataType = "bin.base64"
nodeB64.Text = Mid(base64String, InStr(base64String, ",") + 1)
dim bStream
set bStream = server.CreateObject("ADODB.stream")
bStream.type = 1
bStream.Open()
--> bStream.Write( nodeB64.NodeTypedValue )
bStream.SaveToFile Server.Mappath("../Signatures/" & ImageFileName), 2
bStream.close()
set bStream = nothing
end function
```

P.S. Canvas and drawing on it works perfect.

P.S. 1 Looks like cannot load jquery libraries..

Thank you very much.